# Resolve type with explicit instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-configuration

I use AutoFac. I have to resolve a type with an explicit instance which I get from another service.

For example: I have an instance of type `Client` which I get from somewhere (not from the container).

I want to configure the Autofac container so that always when an object of type `Client` should be resolved, it should return my instance.

Problem is that I don't have this instance at the time, when I configure the container with the `Containerbuilder` - so I cannot use for example `LambdaRegistration`.

Is there another solution for solving my problem?

Comment: Where is this object coming from such that it's NEITHER available before container creation NOR can it be obtained as the result of calling a method on a service that is registered with the container?

Comment: It is read and deserialized from the config. I read an Array of Client-Objects from the Config. After I execute a Service for each Client-Object - each in its own scope. This service uses other services which needs Property-Values of the Client-Object. Now I have thought it would be nice that I can register the Client-Object and this service can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```cs
MyService service = null;

builder.Register(c => service).As<IMyService>();

// Later on
service = new MyService();
```

Depending on your needs there are quite some variations of this approach possible, such as:

- Send a 'setter' delegate to some initialization code that will call the delegate after the service gets created, e.g. `MyServiceInitializer.AfterInitialization(s => service = s);`
- Promote the `service` variable to a class property and provide that new wrapper to the initialization
- Hide access to the service behind specific read and write abstractions, e.g. `interface IMyServiceContext { IMyService Current { get; } }` and `interface IMyServiceSetter { void SetCurrent(IMyService service); }`.
- Prevent Autofac from accidentally resolving the service before it is initialized by throwing an exception instead of throwing null, e.g. `Register(c => service ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("..."))`

It's important to note, however, that in general, the creation of components should be fast and reliable. The fact that your component isn't available at startup is likely because it requires I/O to setup. This is a situation should should try to prevent, for instance by hiding it behind an abstraction completely. This allows you to implement a Proxy that allows the real service to be lazy loaded.

Hopefully this gives you some clues on how to solve this.